# How to keep windows 2003 Daylight Saving values updated

Tags: windows-update, date-time, time-zone

My web app runs on windows 2003 .Net 3.5

I have users from Israel (GMT +2), and Israel switched to Daylight saving time on 26/3/10 so now it's (GMT +3).

I use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime that doesn’t know the Daylight saving time switch is on 26/3/10 so it still converts to GMT +2.

I asked on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530834/problem-with-timezoneinfo-converttime-missed-the-daylight-saving-switch/2532104#2532104

And I was told that I need to update:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Israel Standard Time\Dynamic DST

I found this update:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976098

That supposes to fix the Dynamic DST for 2010, Is this the update I need?

Where can I find an update that handles 2011 2012… ?

Will I need to update my windows every year to get the DST right?

Answer (score 1):

> Will I need to update my windows every year to get the DST right?

Yes. Some countries determine the dates they will have DST every year (and in Australia's case, Western Australia decided they're not having it next year), so you need to keep updating your computer.